# How to render LaTeX correctly within function help pane in Rstudio?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

Mathematical equations written in LaTeX are often presented within the function documentation accessed in R via `help()` or `?` and presented in the help pane in Rstudio. They do not render correctly within the help pane of Rstudio on my machine. I am however able to use LaTeX successfully in all other application and with knitR outputs.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```

Output from Terminal showing my LaTeX version

```
latex -v
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.21; using libpng 1.6.21
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

E.g. when I input `?glm()` the following function description loads in Rstudio:

[image: glm() helpfile with incorrectly rendered LaTeX code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help in `R` renders essentially in HTML or LaTeX. The `.Rd` files that the documentation is written in are rendered as PDF manual, the help page showing upon `?topic` or `help("topic")` call is the HTML one and this does not any math rendering, it is basically only enclosed in `<i>` `</i>` tags.

It is really a shame that the HTML form of the documentation that is used the most completely resigns over the math typesetting. One would think that `R` as "statistical environment" should definitely handle that. Long story short - this behaviour is no error.

However, actually, if you are a package developer and you care about your users' sanity, there is a way how to achieve that math correctly renders in RStudio Help pane, see https://github.com/wviechtb/mathjaxr.

EDIT: I have created a package that hacks Rd to HTML documentation "conversion" which enables proper math rendering for EVERY help page, see https://github.com/netique/documath. It is a sort of monkey patch, but works well. I am in contact with R developers, so maybe we'll see the feature in a proper release. However, that's for a long run.

EDIT2: R 4.2.0+ actually implements the feature from the aforementioned package, so if you want to see the math rendered properly in HTML help, update your R.